# Get friends' faces when using custom Facebook Login

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

When using the Facebook login button, it's possible to set `data-show-faces=true` to list the friends that use the app. I realize this happens automatically and inside an iframe rendered on the Facebook domain, which is where I assume the relevant difference lies.

Is it possible to achieve the same result when creating a custom login button with `FB.login();`, before the user has authenticated the application?

If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, before the user authorized your App there is no way to get his friends. You don´t even know who the user is before `FB.login`. After authorization, you can use the `/me/friends` endpoint to get his friends.

Comment: The point is exactly that I don't want to use an endpoint requiring a token from the user, as that defeats the purpose. I guess this is only possible with the Facebook button because that's served by facebook.com

Comment: exactly, you can only achieve that with social plugins made by facebook